# "Gray out" options in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I am trying to use jQuery to "gray out" options that won't work under one category.

i.e. Option 1 is selected
Sub-option 2 and sub-option 3 are available options under the selected filter, but Sub-Option 1 is not available. So, we need Sub-Option 1 to be "grayed out" so the user knows it can't be selected.

Here's what we have so far: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNgXMe

```
$(function(){
  $('#Container').mixItUp({
    controls: {
        toggleFilterButtons: true,
    toggleLogic: 'and'
    },
    callbacks: {
      onMixEnd: function(state){
        console.log(state.activeFilter)     
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I either can't reproduce it or don't understand your scenario.

Comment: Basically, using javascript, we'd like to prohibit users from clicking options that don't go with their current selection.